# Get bigger icon from System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the associated file type icon in my `WPF` app. Currently I can get the `32x32` version using `System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath)`. However, I want the biggest available icon. How can I achieve this?

For example I want to get the icon for HTML files like the one below (shown in my Explorer):

[image]

Comment: I am not in a position to test this, so will comment. Have you tried passing the icon to `new Icon(originalIcon, new Size(256, 256))`? This  will attempt to resolve the 256x256 size within `originalIcon`. If it doesn't have that size, the closest smaller size will be resolved.

Comment: @KentBoogaart Tried, didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: you're certain that the icon in question actually has a variant greater than 32x32? Have you tried extracting the icon from other places where you know that there's a large variant available?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the image attached above.